# Removing black background on slightly transparent object in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, photoshop-effects, lighting-effects

I have searched for an answer on how to remove a black background to make a transparent image, but none have answered my specific question.

Here I have rendered a scene with a light-emitting cube.  Unfortunately, Blender 3D (the software I used for rendering) doesn't allow me to make the background transparent while also keeping the edge glow, so I want to achieve this effect in photoshop.  Many of the answers involve using a screen blend mode, but that will not work for me because I will need the image with a transparent background, not another solid color background.

[image]

How can I remove the black background of this image while also keeping the edge glow of this object?  The final image should have a semi-transparent background because the edge glow should be semi-transparent.

Comment: This is fairly easily recreated in Photoshop alone via Outer Glow Layer Styles on a hexagon shape layer.

Comment: @Scott I actually tried that but it's not sustainable for other parts of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it.

First, convert the file to Lab mode. Select the L channel. Increase the black a little to make it more black. I used Levels with black output to 10. Now we can use the L channel to load a selection.<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd>.

Back to Layers panel, I created two new Layers and fill then using the colors I show in the image below.  <kbd>alt</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

After a lot of attempts, that is the best match I found.
Just convert it again in RGB and save the file as PNG.

Edit: Remember to hide or delete the background before saving the file.

[image]